# How to get all the contents inside an HTML tag for selected div asp.net codebehind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to get all form variables inside the selected div?

e.g: `this.Page.Request.Form[""]` this will return all data but can it get data within a selected div?

e.g :

```
<div id="a">
    <input type = "text" id="input1">
    <input type = "text" id="input2">
</div>  
<div id="b" style="display:none">
    <input type = "text" id="input1">
    <input type = "text" id="input2">
</div>
```

both div are must.

Answer (score 1):

Your tags are confusing versus your question. It looks like you want to get this information on the post, correct? So, jQuery is not in play after submit.

What I might recommend is you give all of your div inputs the same name so when the form is posted, the form variables will instead have an array of values.

Something like this:

```
<div id="a">
    <input type = "text" id="a_input1" name="div_a">
    <input type = "text" id="a_input2" name="div_a">
</div>  
<div id="b" style="display:none">
    <input type = "text" id="b_input1" name="div_b">
    <input type = "text" id="b_input2" name="div_b">
</div>
```

Then on the server you would access the values like: `this.Page.Request.Form["div_a"].Split(',')[0]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery it would be like this:

```
$('#a :input')
```

Where `#a` is the id of your div, and the pseudo selector `:input` will match any form elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access values of fields by name, you can give each input fields a distinctive name to group them under respective divs, such as:

```
    <div id="a">
        <input type="text" id="input1" name="diva_input1" />
        <input type="text" id="input2" name="diva_input2" />
    </div>
    <div id="b" style="display: none">
        <input type="text" id="input3" name="divb_input1" />
        <input type="text" id="input4" name="divb_input2" />
    </div>
```

Therefore, in code behind, access the values of fields under `<div id="a">` will be:

```
    Dim keyvalues = From key As String In Request.Form.AllKeys Where key.StartsWith("diva_") Select Key = key, Value = Request.Form(key)

    For Each itm In keyvalues
        Debug.WriteLine(itm.Key & "=" & itm.Value)
    Next
```

Sorry my code sample is in VB though.